# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.core'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

After installing tensorflow-gpu using pip3, I am getting the following error when trying to `import tensorflow as tf`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dlpda/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/dlpda/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.core'
```

Although I am able to import successfully in a virtualenv, but not outside.

How should I resolve this problem to be able to import tensorflow?

Comment: Was the package also installed outside of the virtualenv?

Comment: try pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: @kstullich Yes, installed outside of the virtualenv and inside too, but works only inside.

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen Yes, did upgrade.

Comment: @AjinkyaGhadge OK sounds like you have multiple installations outside of your virtualenv in multiple locations. Update your path so that the location of /home/dlpda/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ is no longer in your python path. Type 'echo $PATH' and/or 'echo $PYTHONPATH' - it will help u debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be with packages installation directories like some packages are installed in home and some in /usr/. 
I suggest you to remove all the packages in home directory by finding them in 
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
and reinstall then with super user privileges.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bug in tensorflow. In 1.13, we have an `__init__.py` that contains:

```py
__all__ = [_s for _s in dir() if not _s.startswith('_')]

# ... later ...
try:                                                                                                                                                                       
  del python
  del core
```

So while we remove `python` and `core` from the module, we do not remove them from `__all__`. This prevents use cases like `from tensorflow import *`. This should be fixed in Tensorflow 1.14 with [this change](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/5a93bb319c3672e9d6fe604e3611095116cb5fcc).

Answer (score 1):

Please create a virtual environment and then install tensorflow into that. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in tensorflow 1.15 with django 2.1.0 and python 3.7.4

It was working fine with tensorflow 1.14 with django 2.1.0 and python 3.7.4.

There is some issue in latest version of tensorflow(2.0/1.15) with previous version of django. same issue is observed with previous version of flask also.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34607

Proposed solution is to update your django version from 2.1.0 > 2.2.5 , it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue (`Error importing: No module named 'tensorflow.core.kernels.boosted_trees'`) this worked out:

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall tensorflow
```